# React how to place images in a row

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hey I'm struggling to place two images right next to each other with some space between them
After a long search the closest I got was this:

[image]

As you can see there's no space between the images and I tried to change that with marginRight or paddingRight however nothing seems to change it..
Here's my code:

```
let stylereg_na = { alignItems: "center", flex: 1, height: hp('7%'), width: wp('7%')};
let stylereg_eu = {height: hp('10%'), width: wp('9%')};

return (
<View style={styles.container}>

<View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>

<View style={{alignItems: "center", flex: 1, paddingTop: 15, paddingBottom : 15}}>
<img style={stylereg_na} src ={na}>
</View>

<View style={{ alignItems: "center", paddingTop: 15, paddingBottom : 15 }}>
<img style={stylereg_eu} src ={eu}/>
</View>

</View>
</View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
backgroundColor: '#D8D8D8',
alignItems: 'center',
justifyContent: 'center',
},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://codesandbox.io/s/image-with-space-evenly-xojsy

Try adding `padding:15` to your view that wraps the image as shown below

```
  <View style={{padding: 15}}>
        <Image style={stylereg_na} source={na} />
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the `Image` component provided by React Native https://reactnative.dev/docs/image.  Also, your parent container is utilizing `justify-content` `space-between` so you should not neet to use padding or margin as long as you want flex to figure out the spacing for you.

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Image } from "react-native";

const ViewBoxesWithColorAndText = () => {
let stylereg_na = { height: 50, width: 50};
let stylereg_eu = { height: 50, width: 50};

  return (
    <View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>

      <View style={{alignItems: "center", flex: 1, paddingTop: 15, paddingBottom : 15}}>
        <Image style={stylereg_na} source={na} />
      </View>

      <View style={{ alignItems: "center", paddingTop: 15, paddingBottom : 15 }}>
        <Image style={stylereg_eu} source={eu}/>
      </View>

    </View>
  );
};

export default ViewBoxesWithColorAndText;
```

Comment: even after using your code, the images have no space between them...

Comment: I tested this locally and confirmed that it does work.  Are you sure your images aren't bigger than the container?

Answer (score 0):

add `paddingLeft:15`
or `paddingRight:15` to style

Comment: I've tried that, for some reason, it doesn't do anything

Comment: can you share your code on snack?   ``https://snack.expo.io/``